# Is it possible to smooth text change in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was working on a content changing click feature with JavaScript and jQuery and it works but is clunky. Is there anyway to make this transition smoother within JS or jQuery?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1").click(function() {
    if (document.getElementById("frst_hd").innerHTML === "World") {
      document.getElementById("frst_hd").innerHTML = "Hello";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("frst_hd").innerHTML = "World";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="frst_hd">Hello</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm pretty new in this language so I'm sorry if this issue is easy to solve. Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you expect from a transition between two different strings? There are different ways of doing such effects

Comment: @Itay I'd be okay with something as simple as a slide fade type deal if feasible.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Absolutely if you can do this on click!

Comment: your expected to do this yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1").click(function() {
    if (document.getElementById("frst_hd").innerHTML === "World") {
      $("#frst_hd").hide().text("Hello").fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
      $("#frst_hd").hide().text("World").fadeIn(1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="frst_hd">Hello</h1>
</body>

</html>
```